# Can Bluetooth headphones work with Wii U?

Tags: wii-u

I have a pair of Bluetooth headphones, and I would like to use them with my Wii U. Is there any way I can do that **without** using any special addons?

Comment: Okay, so just to confirm - you're looking for ways to do this natively with the WiiU, without using outside products/peripherals/software?

Comment: Yes. Just the Wii U by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've read, it looks like the Wii U does **not** support wireless headphones through bluetooth.

What you *can* do if you're able, though, is plug your wireless headphones (if they have an audio receiver attachment) into your T.V.'s audio output and then listen from there. Not all T.V.'s have this, so otherwise you are out of luck.

Comment: If you have one of the wireless headphones whose receiver attachment plugs in using a 3.5 mm jack, you can try to plug those into the Wii U Gamepad 3.5 mm audio output hole. If that ends up being successful, I'll update my answer (because I've seen conflicting reports on if that works or not).

Comment: Thanks anyway. Oh well. I have regular headphones too, just curious.

Comment: @Guy The gamepad output certainly works with standard 3.5mm headphones - and the volume is obviously controlled on the gamepad, not the TV. I haven't tried it with Bluetooth headphones with a 3.5mm receiver but there's little reason why that shouldn't work, I would think!

Comment: Some T.V.'s have an audio output as well. Yeah, and I would hope that the Gamepad output would work but hardware can be weird and since I haven't tested it for myself I can't say for absolute certain if it works or not.